# Why is my Shell Sort so slow?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, sorting, shellsort

I'm trying to implement a bunch of sorting algorithms in JavaScript, and I can't figure out why my shell sort is so slow. It's 6x slower than my merge sort, and only slightly faster than my insertion sort. I've seen another implementation online, but I'm more focused on making it clear and readable (as I have a blog for noobs) and the faster implementation is too concise for my purposes. Any thoughts on how I can keep the general plan but get it moving faster?

```
  var shellSort = function( list ) {
    var gapSize = Math.floor( list.length / 2 );

    while( gapSize > 0 ) {
      _shellInsertionSort( list, gapSize );
      gapSize = Math.floor( gapSize / 2 );
    }

    return list;
  };

  function _shellInsertionSort( list, gapSize ) {
    var temp, i, j;

    for( i = gapSize; i < list.length; i += gapSize ) {
      j = i;
      while( j > 0 && list[ j - gapSize ] > list[j] ) {
        temp = list[j];
        list[j] = list[ j - gapSize ];
        list[ j - gapSize ] = temp;
        j -= gapSize;
      }
    }
  };
```

My merge sort:

```
  var mergeSort = function( list ) {
    if ( list.length <= 1 ) {
      return list;
    }

    var left = [],
        right = [],
        middle = Math.floor( list.length / 2 ),
        i;

    for( i = 0; i < middle; i++ ) {
      left.push( list[i] );
    }

    for( ; i < list.length; i++ ) {
      right.push( list[i] );
    }

    left = mergeSort( left );
    right = mergeSort( right );

    return _merge( left, right );
  };

  function _merge( left, right ) {
    var result = [];

    // Should be able to just get rid of arguments in while loop
    while( left.length || right.length ) {
      if( left.length > 0 && right.length > 0 ) {
        if( left[0] <= right[0] ) {
          result.push( left.shift() );
        } else {
          result.push( right.shift() );
        }
      } 
      else if( left.length ) {
        return result.concat( left );
      } 
      else {
        return result.concat( right );
      }
    }
  }
```

My tests:

```
  var testSpeed = function( testSize, rounds ) {
    var testArrays = [],
        algorithms = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 2 ),
        results = [],
        i, j;

    for( i = 0; i < rounds; i++ ) {
      testArrays[i] = [];
      for( j = 0; j < testSize; j++ ) {
        testArrays[i].push( Math.ceil( Math.random() * testSize ));
      }
    }

    for( i = 0; i < algorithms.length; i++ ) {
      for( j = 0; j < rounds; j++ ) {
        if( !results[i] ) {
          results[i] = [];
        }
        results[i].push( testAlgorithm( algorithms[i], testArrays[j] ));
      }
    }

    return results;
  };

  var testAlgorithm = function( algorithm, set ) {
    var clone = set.slice(),
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        end;

    algorithm( clone );

    end = new Date().getTime();

    return end - start;
  };
```

Comment: This may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Shell sort is quadratic in the worst case with your gap sequence, so why do you think it should *not* be slower than merge sort?

Comment: Although I didn't check your code at all thoroughly (and codereview is likely a better place to ask for a code review), I believe that the gap sequence you're using is not very good; unlike other gap sequences, it has O(N^2) worst case time complexity.

Comment: @NiklasB.: That depends on the interval sequence you use. See Sedgewick 1996 (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.101.9061) for a survey of complexity results.

Comment: @rici I took the gap sequence into account, which is particularly poorly chosen here. But even with a good gap sequence you are unlikely to beat merge sort asymptotically

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and pointing me to codereview. I'm not a CS guy, and calculating O accurately is beyond my skills. I used Marcin Ciura's gap sequence [704, 301, 132...], but the performance was worse, which is probably because of my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I put your algorithms together, made a function that simply samples it, records time (with millis() instead of how you test it which i don't understand) and outputs an average time. Shell sort is 0.02 milliseconds for an array of 100 numbers.. not taking into account that most millisecond recordings are floored with shell sort (since it's sometimes 0). I did the same with merge sort and it's 0.21 milliseconds.. Hope this answers it https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/sort-algorithms/6199294078746624